# wood tongue and grove ceiling - does it need drywall under it for fire protection.

Tags: wood, ceiling

I want to install wood tongue and grove cedar wood ceiling in my family room and kitchen in a single story home. I plan on removing the existing drywall since the ceiling height is low and I don't want it lower if possible. My family room has a brick fireplace with an insert. Also the ceiling uses 1 by 3 slats that go perpendicular to the 1 by 6 ceiling joists to hold the drywall. My existing drywall ceiling has water damage. So my options are:

1. Remove drywall and 1x3 slats and Attach wood ceiling to ceiling joists (will raise the ceiling height by 3/4 inch).
2. Attach wood ceiling through existing drywall (lowers ceiling by 1/2 inch yet offers more fire protection).
3. Replace the existing drywall ceiling with more drywall.

I want to use option 1. Is it ok? Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Are you seriously concerned about the loss or gain of ceiling height that is less than one inch? If you are working with standard ceiling height if 96 inches you are quibbling about something just over 1% difference.

Comment: If you're worried about the height of the ceiling, then cedar may be a poor choice.  In general, the darker the ceiling, the lower it will seem visually.  Even raising it a couple inches and panelling it will likely make it **appear** lower than a white ceiling.

Comment: Michael, well yes inches matter to me. I am kind of tall and am use to taller ceilings. We may be putting in a tile floor and it will reduce the ceiling height even more. For my head height it is not a simple 1% since it is the distance from the top of my head to the bottom of the ceiling that I care about. To me all walls should be at least 9 feet high. But I do appreciate your comment and would in general agree with your comment.

Comment: Cominterm, you have a good point. Most of our house is brightly colored and there is white ceilings in all rooms. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

No, gypsum board is not required on the ceiling, unless 1) HOA requires gypsum board for fire protection, 2) local Planning Department requires it due to proximity encroachment to property lines, 3) you live in a building with more than 3 units.

However, the existing gypsum board “seals” the room from the attic, so you won’t get air infiltration blown in from the attic and around all the cracks between the ceiling boards.

If you really need the height, you might be able to remove the gypsum board and install plastic wrap to eliminate the air infiltration. (Be sure to seal all the joints with tape.)

Answer (score 0):

I think option #2 makes the most sense.   If you aren't glueing it you can remove the wood at a later date and just have to skim coat the ceiling to refinish it.

There are too many issues with removing it, all the way from it being a mess to losing the natural vapor/air barrier sheets of gypsum provide... your slats won't be as good.   And I am not even getting into fire rating.   (City may have a minimum thickness for these so you better check - they may even require backing)

On an aesthetic note... These kinds of ceilings can look great.   But they have to fit the craftsmanship of the home and the style.   These ceiling are normally not done on "flat" ceilings either (accept for maybe porches/sunrooms) so it better be done pretty damn air tight on the install as an blemishes/miscuts/slanting/whatever will stick out.